# Embed Spotify not working properly at Android's Webview

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, embed, spotify

I was using embed spotify in a webview inside my app and everything was working fine. But it suddenly stopped working. Now, every time I click play button or click at a song from the playlist it redirects me to "spotify:playlist:(playlist code)". I'm actually capturing this intent, but I wanted the song to play inside webview, without redirecting to spotify's app, like it used to be.

My WebViewClient:

```
class MyWebViewClient(private val originUrl: String?) : WebViewClient() {

    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String?): Boolean {
        if (Uri.parse(url).scheme.containsIntent(listOf("market", "whatsapp", "spotify"))){
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            intent.data = Uri.parse(url)
            val host: Activity = view?.context as Activity
            host.startActivity(intent)

            view.loadUrl(originUrl)
            return true
        }


        return false
    }
}
```

I am actually initializing it inside a recycler view:

```
class WebViewHolder(itemView: View) : ViewHolder(itemView),
    HolderInterface {
    private val webView: WebView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.webview)
    private var link: String? = null

    init {
        webView.webChromeClient = WebChromeClient()
    }

    override fun bind(message: Message) {
        if (link == null){
            link = message.text

            webView.webViewClient = MyWebViewClient(link)

            webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true

            webView.setOnTouchListener { view, _ ->
                view.parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
                false
            }

            webView.loadUrl(link)
        }
    }
}
```

Inflating it with this layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingStart="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:paddingEnd="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp" >

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/bot_image"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:thicknessRatio="1.9"
        app:cardCornerRadius="30dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/chat_bot_avatar"/>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/bot_image"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/bot_image">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:clickable="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm testing this webview with this link: `https://open.spotify.com/embed/playlist/27XP00bk55vpUc9KaQoIjz`.

It used to work inside my recycler view. I made no changes at my webview files since then.

Is there something wrong with this code?

[EDIT]

I actually found out that this bug is not happening at most phones. Until now, mine is the only afected, not only at the app, but at browsers too (web sites that contains embed spotify).. Has anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The Spotify requires external permissions for Webview.

Try implementing in `onPermissionRequest()` in your `WebChromeClient`.

```
 override fun onPermissionRequest(request: PermissionRequest?) {
            val resources = request?.resources
            for (i in resources?.indices!!) {
                if (PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_PROTECTED_MEDIA_ID == resources[i]) {
                    request.grant(resources)
                    return
                }
            }
            super.onPermissionRequest(request)
        }
```